# Wrong colors when loading texture form MTL file in three js

Tags: colors, three.js, mtl-file

The colors I get when loading the model are slightly warmer than the texture itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your three ka and cd values in the mtl file should be 1

Ka 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
Kd 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).